# Creating a Word document in C++- CLI using OpenXML SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-word, c++-cli, openxml

How to create a word document in OpenXML using C++-CLI, I have configured CLR with visual studio.

Please guide me through code( or please post a compiling code)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off with libopc.  See further http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmahugh/archive/2011/04/19/libopc-version-0-0-1-released.aspx